# Fork-Exec Bomb without loops

Tags: c, linux, fork, infinite-loop

I am learning C and have run into a small problem. After reading about `fork()` bomb on Wikipedia and on StackOverflow. I wanted to implement the same, but using command line args.

I want to endlessly call firefox/chrome, but unable to do the same in my below program. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t pid;
    char *parmList[] = {"firefox", "index.html", NULL};
    int a;

    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        perror("fork failed");
    }
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        a = execvp("/usr/bin/firefox", parmList);
        fprintf(stdout, "execvp() returned %d\n", a);
        fprintf(stdout, "errno: %s (%d).\n", strerror(errno), errno);
    }
    else
    {
        waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, you’re forking once. Maybe try doing it more?

Comment: It's not executing, I tried using a while loop and giving args, for example `myProgram firefox`

Comment: `execvp()` never returns if successful; the current process is *replaced* with the executed binary instead. Therefore, your `fprintf(stdout, ...);` lines are only executed if executing Firefox **fails**. In normal, successful case, you see no output. If it started the first copy of Firefox, the parent just "hangs" until last Firefox window gets closed; if Firefox was already open, the program returns immediately. Just because you don't see what you expect, does not mean *"It's not executing"*.

Answer (score 0):

You should clarify what error you're getting, since I don't want to run a fork bomb, but the code you wrote doesn't bomb (call `fork()` within a loop). It spawns one process, waits nicely, and quits.

Comment: It's not even doing opening firefox/chrome once when I use command line args

Comment: If neither `fork()` nor `execvp()` reports an error, and this only happens when you give arguments, Firefox is running and quitting immediately.  Does `index.html` actually exist in the current working directory?

Comment: `execvp() returned -1`
`errno: No such file or directory (2).` I removed 'index.html' and still the errors.

Comment: Then you aren't using the correct path for Firefox.  Find it with `whereis firefox`, and replace the quoted string with a `const char program_path[]` that contains the right one.

Comment: Is Firefox installed on your machine?  Might reinstall it to make sure.  Or you might have iceweasel.

Comment: Yes, can fork-exec bomb be creating without using loops

Comment: Sure; you can `fork` from a tail-recursive function, but that doesn't seem to be your problem.